# How to get multiple objects of a model without using filter?

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django 2.2, we can use `filter()` to get a `QuerySet` of created objects. Using `list()`, I can have a list of `QuerySet`.

In order to get an instance of a model I can use the function `get()`, for instance `MyModel.objects.all().get(name__exact="John")`. However, the `get()` function works only for finding a single object. If if finds 2 or more objects, it returns an exception: `MultipleObjectsReturned get() returned more than one`.

Since I need to process the multiple object of my model and its attributes, I would like to get a list of objects. Is it possible? For example, I want to create a list of ages from all objects with John in the attribute name.

If not, how can I access an attribute (e.g. age) of the returned QuerySet from the `MyModel.objects.all().filter(name__exact="John")`?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You kinda have the answer already. By doing `Model.objects.filter(...)` you have a Queryset which behaves like a list. That'll return multiple objs by given criteria. If you need an explicit list, you can just wrap that queryset in a `list()` like you already know. You can iterate through your Queryset and process what you need.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that QuerySet behaves like a list. Thanks Higor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `values`:

```
instances = MyModel.objects.filter(name__exact="John")
ages = instances.values('id', 'age')
```

You'll get a list of dictionaries with keys `id` and `age`.